# Trying to install Tensorflow-Probability using reticulate - how to specify user?

Tags: r, reticulate, greta

In order to install the `greta` package, I need to first install tensorflow-probability. Tensorflow and Python 3.7 Anaconda are already installed.

When I attempt the following command in R: `reticulate::conda_install("r-tensorflow", "tensorflow-probability", pip = TRUE)`, I get the following:

```
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 
'C:\\Users\\PHILTE~1\\ANACON~1\\envs\\r-tensorflow\\Lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\core\\multiarray.cp36-win_amd64.pyd'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

I have admin permissions on my laptop, so I'm unsure why I'm getting an access denied. But how do I add the `--user` command within the `reticulate` command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This webpage fixed it all for me: http://preposterior.updog.co/november-8-2018-getting-your-computing-environment-ready-for-greta.html#november-8-2018-getting-your-computing-environment-ready-for-greta

Steps:

1. Install [Anaconda](https://conda.io/miniconda.html)
2. Open Anaconda Prompt and run the following:

`conda activate r-tensorflow`

`pip install --no-dependencies tensorflow-probability==0.4.0`

`conda install tensorflow=1.11`

`pip install h5py pyyaml requests Pillow scipy`

3. Back in R, install the `greta` package from CRAN.

Answer (score 1):

From version 0.4.0, `greta` now includes a `install_greta_deps()` function that installs all the relevant python modules required for `greta`.

You can learn more here:

https://greta-stats.org/articles/get_started.html